# My enemy in my Top Down shooter keeps teleporting left and right of the player but doesn't follow it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following script is supposed to make the enemy sprite follow the player, but all it does is teleport left and right of the player.

The speed I set is connected to the distance the enemy teleports. If you need anything else besides this script, just tell me I'm quite new to Unity and C#.

The error I'm getting is:

> Assertion failed on expression: 'task.rasterData.vertexBuffer == NULL'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

And my code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D target;
    public float speed = 10f;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 dir = target.position - rb.position;
        rb.MovePosition(dir.normalized * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont want the position of the rigid body, on the character, you want the players transform.. change target to GameObject, stop and the player, and use its position

Answer (score 0):

As BugFinder says, yo need the transform. Also although you are working in 2d, a transform's position is a vector3. Find some modifications as suggestions for your code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 10f;

    public Transform rb;

    void Start()
    {
        //You can get these programatically or attach them ni the editor. Seems that 
        //target is the player and the rb is the follower. You can make the variables 
        //public attach them in the editor so that they can be accessed in the code

        // rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        // target = 
        //GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = target.position - rb.position;
        rb.position = rb.position + (dir.normalized * speed);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps